# I called the data and tried using fetch_assoc but nothing appeared

Tags: php, mysqli

I made this to display data but nothing appeared, 
and it shows no errors in coding

is there anyone who can help me

```
<?php
require 'db_connect.php';
$sql_get = "SELECT * FROM daftarumkm ORDER BY id_daftar DESC";
$query = $con->query($sql_get);
$response_data = null;
while ($data = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $response_data[] = $data;
}
if (is_null($response_data)) {
        $status = true;
} else {
    $status = true;
}
```

and this is db_connect.php

```
<?php
define('DB_USER', "root"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', "data_umkm"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); // db server

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

// Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve (or display)? I see that you're just setting the $status to true?

Comment: So, Echo $status;

Comment: You need `$response_data` or you are just keeping to check `$status`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code for getting data from the database is fine, but there are some other issues.

1) If you want to check whether you got the results from database in the variable `$response_data` you have made a mistake here

```
if (is_null($response_data)) {
        $status = true;
} else {
    $status = true;
}
```

You probably want to change it to

```
if (is_null($response_data)) {
        $status = false;
} else {
    $status = true;
}
```

and I should mention thet there is a better way to do this. Instead of 4 lines above, you can simply write `$status = (is_null($response_data)) ? false : true;`

2) Furthermore, instead of all of the lines

```
$response_data = null;
while ($data = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $response_data[] = $data;
}
if (is_null($response_data)) {
        $status = true;
} else {
    $status = true;
}
```

you can write the following more efficient code:

```
$response_data = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$status = ($response_data) ? false : true;
```

3) At the end, if you want to see the results, simply use the `var_dumb()` function.

```
var_dumb($response_data);
```

Comment: `(empty($response_data))` is redundant. You can simply cast `$response_data` to a bool type.

Comment: @Dharman You are right. I fixed that in the answer. Thank you!

Comment: it's works for me now, thank you

Comment: @Diva You're welcome. If it worked why you did not accept the answer.